# Apply a glow effect onto a THREE.TextGeometry object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have done quite a few hours of google search to see if this can be done
within the three.js environment.

I want to create a glow effect based on a TextGeometry and not a simple primitive like a sphere or cube object similar to the one in Lee StemKoski - shadow glow example below.

[image: Lee StemKoski - shadow glow example]

I have been reading and experimenting with [Lee StemKoski examples](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/index.html)

In particular with his [Shader Glow example](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html) which as stated works well with simple objects but not with complex geometric shapes. Therefore I was wondering if there are any work arounds to this or other suggestions to how one could create a glow effect around text.

regards

w9914420

UPDATE: I decided to go with the mapping concept by attaching an image to the text I can create a glow effect. In this example I used a circle, but should not be too difficult to do a map for the text that I need.

[image: sprite glow effect]

UPDATE: 20/3/17 - So I had an attempt at using the theeX.atmosphere material to create that elusive text glow effect. Here are some of the results.

[image: threex.atmospherematerial]

[image: angle view]

As you can see not quite there yet - the issue that I have is I am not able to smooth the vertices of the outer glow text more. I am not sure if it is possible any advice appreciated.

Native code used to create effect.

```
//normal text created  

var geometry2  = threeLab.asset.simpleText('hello','my_font');
var materialme  = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var mesh    = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, materialme );
this.scene.add( mesh );


// we create a secondary text object to use as glow
var geometry  = threeLab.asset.simpleText('hello','my_font');

// clone for manipulation
var geoclone = geometry.clone();


//Thes functions are need to make it work in this case
geoclone.mergeVertices();
//geoclone.computeCentroids();
geoclone.computeVertexNormals();
geoclone.computeFaceNormals();

// part of threex library to make the glow scale and expand
THREEx.dilateGeometry(geoclone, 0.5);
var materialz   = THREEx.createAtmosphereMaterial();
var meshHalo    = new THREE.Mesh(geoclone, materialz );

//we have now our glow
this.scene.add( meshHalo );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "glow"? There's lots of ways to interpret that. [Here's one technique](https://willweissman.wordpress.com/tutorials/shaders/unity-shaderlab-object-outlines/comment-page-1/). It's not in three.js but shows a solution. [Here's another different technique which is to use glow maps](http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html).

Comment: @gman My apologises for the confusion I have re-edited my question in reference to the example that I wish to re-create. The effect style that I am after is like this example but with text instead of a simple sphere:     [Shader-Glow-Example](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html)

Comment: Seems like to glow map technique linked above would do what you want.

Comment: Take a look at [threex.geometricglow](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.geometricglow)

Comment: @prisoner849 Hey many thanks for this I will need to investigate further tnxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So In the end I increased the **bevelsegments** of my secondary TextGeometry object which helped to smooth it. I was then able to encase my first text into the second like so:

[image]

[image]

With further tweaking I will be able to get the glow effect more subtle, but for now the effect works.

Thank you all for the input :)